# ADD Datagridview values to database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a datagridview that i fill and after i click on a button and all the rows goes to my database, that is working, but when i want to insert more rows and insert into the database it insert all the rows again and i just want the last ones added.
If anyone could help me i appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment so I will write here...

So if I do understand you correctly you are filling gridview sending it to database. After that you fill once more the gridview and send it but this time it also send the one already are on the gridview?

---

**Edit/Update** *(after the extra info [see below comments])*

 You can use the `SELECT` statment to put only values that does not exist.

 Before you start using this method/statment you need to know very well which values can be put multiple times so you will write your WHERE statment that way...

 
 I did make a example for you check it out: 
**[Example on DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f6f44ed70cee033d5f515fdabccdac2)**

 There are also another option of you doing this and it is using the `IF` statment. I will also make a SQLFIDDLE of this but first I need to go to the market and will edit this post with that too once I come home.

Comment: yes, i fill my dgv and after i send it to my database, and if i want to add more rows on the dgv and send to database it will send all again and i just want this last rows not the older

Comment: What you can do is make a gridview to SHOW and one to ADD.
Or what you also can do is use IF NOT EXISTS 
You also need to update your question with examples etc... Since now it is very general and we can't help you without you putting what you are using (code)

Comment: Oh ok, look i have a datagridview empty, so i put values on it and i click on a button to save it to my database, after that i can leave the dgv menu and come back, when i click on it again it will pick the older values of datagridview and insert into dgv again, so i can add more values and after that click on save again and ALL of this will save in the db and of course i dont want repeated values on the db, just this last values that i add

Comment: INSERT table VALUES("&nomedatarefa, &iniciar, &terminar, &duração, &atribuido, &prioridade, &status, &comentários)

Comment: This is the insert i use in vb.net to my db

Comment: With the Parameters.Add bellow

Comment: I did edit your and mine post. I hope this will help you out and try next time to edit your own post please :)

Comment: Ok,  i tested your code in vb nad i can insert a row in my db but if i try to add another row its breaks my programa and it gives me an error

Comment: happy that you figured it out mate :)